# Chmod 777 in Windows 7

Tags: windows, command-line

I use Window 7 and I need to create a new `.dat` file in the principal partition `C:`. But I can't do that because I don't have all the permissions.

I run the cmd as administrator and I try again but the problem persist again.

I need to now what's the command line that can do this task.

In one word, I need the equivalent of  Linux' `chmod 777` in `Microsoft-dos' in order to change the permissions.

Comment: Please include the command(s) you tried to run and the error message(s). As such the question with the answer(s) would be much more useful for other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specifically, for file permission changes in Windows from the DOS prompt you can use CACLS( which appears to be not used anymore ) and more recently ICACLS

Examples:

To grant the Users group Full Control to a folder:

> icacls "C:\MyFolder" /grant Users:F

To grant a specific user full control over D:\test folder and all its subfolders:

> C:>icacls "D:\test" /grant John:(OI)(CI)F

Please check this link for more information :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows

and this one from Microsoft:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: noted - will do in future.

Comment: @Ramhound , done and will remember to do in future.

Comment: Adding a /t would indicate to perform the operation to all the folders within